# Point Cloud Library Build Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library

I am trying to use the Point Cloud Library in conjunction with the kinect for a paper, but when I followed [this tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php), and tried to compile the solution in Visual Studio 2010, I had a couple of build errors:

```
pcd_write.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall pcl::PCDWriter::writeASCII(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const &,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> const &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> const &,int)" (?writeASCII@PCDWriter@pcl@@QAEHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABUPointCloud2@sensor_msgs@@ABV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@ABV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@8@H@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall pcl::PCDWriter::write(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const &,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> const &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> const &,bool)" (?write@PCDWriter@pcl@@UAEHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABUPointCloud2@sensor_msgs@@ABV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@ABV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@8@_N@Z)
pcd_write.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall pcl::PCDWriter::writeBinary(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const &,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> const &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> const &)" (?writeBinary@PCDWriter@pcl@@QAEHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABUPointCloud2@sensor_msgs@@ABV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@ABV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@8@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall pcl::PCDWriter::write(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const &,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> const &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> const &,bool)" (?write@PCDWriter@pcl@@UAEHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABUPointCloud2@sensor_msgs@@ABV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@ABV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@8@_N@Z)
pcd_write.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl pcl::console::print(enum pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL,char const *,...)" (?print@console@pcl@@YAXW4VERBOSITY_LEVEL@12@PBDZZ) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall pcl::PCDWriter::writeASCII<struct pcl::PointXYZ>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class pcl::PointCloud<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const &,int)" (??$writeASCII@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCDWriter@pcl@@QAEHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$PointCloud@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@1@H@Z)
```

Can someone explain why these errors are occurring and how I can fix them? All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Comment: These are linker errors - it looks like the required PCL libraries aren't being linked.  If you add `message("PCL_IO_LIBRARIES - ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES}")` to the foot of your CMakeLists.txt and re-run cmake, you'll see what value(s) are set as dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong PCL version (64 bit / 32 bit). If you are generating a 64 bit CMake project, be sure to install 64bit PCL libraries for Visual Studio 2010. If you are unsure about the version of PCL being used, you can check by following the suggestion from Fraser.

You can download the correct PCL libraries from [here](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html).

Comment: Now I am getting the error: `Unable to start program .../ALL_BUILD. The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Does the project compile without any error? If that's the case, right click on the name of the project which generates executables in Visual Studio's "Project Explorer" and choose "Set as Active" (the project explorer panel should be on the left and should also contain ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK projects). When debugging or executing your project it should ask you for the location of the executables: look for it in the folder containing your project files, usually in the Debug or Release subfolders (depending on the building configuration).

Comment: I am now getting another error saying a DLL wasn't found. This was solved by copying and pasting that DLL from its directory to my project. I could have probably also solved it by adding that DLL to the PATH, but that won't be necessary unless I have another project. I have marked your answer as correct for helping me so much, but I still don't understand why ALL_BUILD isn't working. Doesn't it have a purpose?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Probably, when ALL_BUILD was selected, Visual Studio prompted for an "Executable for Debug Session" but the wrong executable name was provided or it was not provided at all (at least that's how I can recreate your issue on my system). 

You can check [this page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html) for a detailed explaination of the additional helper projects generated by CMake!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same error and I found the solution to it. When you are using cmake, make sure you choose the Visual Studio 10 win64 generators if you are using the 64 bit PCL libraries. I originally used the Visual Studio 10 generators and got the exact same error. When I switched it to Visual Studio 10 win64 generators it worked like a charm.

Comment: Please make this a comment.

Comment: Why would this be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: Glad I could be of help!